# Access SQL "where like left" query unstable

Tags: sql, performance, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a query in Access 2010 that used the following SQL

```
SELECT *
FROM [TABLE1]![STOCK_NUM], [TABLE2]![STOCK_NUM], [TABLE3]![STOCK_NUM]
WHERE [TABLE2]![STOCK_NUM] LIKE LEFT([TABLE1]![STOCK_NUM],11) AND [TABLE3]![STOCK_NUM] LIKE LEFT([TABLE1]![STOCK_NUM],11)
```

The query works correctly but it makes access extremely unstable. I get "Program not responding" when I try to sort or filter it or even go the the last record. There is about 2k - 3k records in each table. Is there a better/more stable method to do this?

Just for a little back story, I can't use the join because I have values in table one that are "12345678912A". I need to match those values to "12345678912" from tables2 and 3

Comment: Do you need to return all of the columns? I see you are doing a select * and if there were columns you didn't need it may help it run more smoothly to specify the ones you do need instead of pulling back all of them.

Comment: Your greatest stability improvement would problem come with redesigning the database/application so that this exact query isn't necessary.

Comment: your query has *fields* in the `from` clause... how on earth does it runs?